Cannot drop DB2 stored procedure due to undefined name error
I have a stored procedure for DB2. I'm unable to drop the procedure. I'm getting the below error while executing the DROP PROCEDURE <PROCEDURE_NAME> command.
Error:

DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=MYSCHEMA.MyProcedure, DRIVER=3.50.152 Message: "MYSCHEMA.MyProcedure" is an undefined name. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.50.152

Procedure details:

ROUTINESCHEMA: MYSCHEMA
ROUTINENAME: MyProcedure
ROUTINETYPE: P
OWNER: ROLEA

Command executed:
DROP PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.MyProcedure;

Error:

"MYSCHEMA.MyProcedure" is an undefined name. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.50.152

Additional information:

The procedure exists in the ROUTINESCHEMA MYSCHEMA.
My procedure has no definition
Unable to view the stored procedure. When I try to open it in the editor, I get an 'object not found' error.

Question
Why am I getting this error and how can I successfully drop the procedure?

DB2 is generally case-sensitive and folds ordinary identifiers to uppercase. Use, delimited identifiers to keep the exact capitalization:
DROP PROCEDURE MY_SCHEMA."MyProcedure";


Check the SPECIFIC_NAME.  Could be you accidently created two procedures with the same name and a different set of parameters.
If so, use DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE ....

Query the catalog to extract the exact specificname (which may be a generated by Db2), and explicitly drop that specific procedure while respecting the CaSe of the specificname. Detail the result in your question.
